# Handling file field values in session

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-requests

Would it be possible to upload a file and store it in a session and send that file using requests in python ? Can someone get back with a detailed answer

Comment: You might want to share what you've tried so far ... :-)

Comment: I have tried `request.session["video"] = request.FILES["video_file"]` and it is treated as **InMemoryUploadedFile**  is not json serializable when it comes in `requests.post` section

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding your need for this type of implementation.

Are you trying to pass a JSON file between sessions? or just any type of file?

It would help to know your idea behind this implementation.